# Can't seem to dump a mysql database

Tags: python, database, django, mysql

I seem to be having a problem. I have a  view where I can allow staff users to download the MySQL database for that program, however it is not working at all. I get an error which says `Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz'`.

I don't know why I get the error, but it the likely answer is because the I can't dump the database properly. It can't find backup.gz, because it cannot find the file beacause the step where it supposed to dump the file does not work.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def dbbackup(request):
    if not (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff):
        raise http.Http404
    os.popen3("mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql")
    os.popen3("gzip -c /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz"
    dataf = open('/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz', 'r')
    return HttpResponse(dataf.read(), mimetype='application/x-gzip')
```

**EDIT:** I have tried  running a small python script. Now the following python file below works (saves a file named backup.gz in the c2duo_mms directory). So why can I not do the same thing from my views.py file!?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

    os.popen3("mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql")
    os.popen3("gzip -c /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz")
```

Comment: I only have a guess and why it's a comment, make sure the user django is running as has the required permissions to write to that directory. Check the output from mysqldump and gzip for errors also.

Comment: Have you tried running the command manually to ensure it works?

Comment: @Mike Ramirez: Permissions are defintely fine. The output for mysqldump and gzip seem fine as well. Although Because it does not dump the database it might be this line that is causing the problem. `os.popen3("mysqldump --add-drop-table -u " + settings.DATABASE_USER + " -p" + settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD + " " + settings.DATABASE_NAME + " >  backup.sql")
    os.popen3("gzip -c backup.sql > backup.gz")
`

Comment: @Shehzad009 then see the first answer posted.  It should solve it. yes I know os.chdir() should do it similarly with relative paths, but absolute paths are usually optimal and you do know where it is going/should be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The webserver was running as a different user than root (it needs to be the same), so I did not have permissions to save in  that folder. I changed the ownership of the folder I wanted to save to which has worked now.

`chown -R "apache" c2duo_mms`

Answer (score 1):

Use a full path here:

```
 os.popen3("mysqldump --add-drop-table -u " + settings.DATABASE_USER + " -p" + settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD + " " + settings.DATABASE_NAME + " >  backup.sql")
```

i.e. Where you are saving down the sql.

Comment: Maybe also try using the full path to the mysqldump command too. Have you been able to debug to determine which part of the script is failing.

Comment: Also worth checking. Do you see the sql file in the folder? I note that there is no rm command, so you would expect to see both files remain. If it's not there, this would suggest that the dump is failing, if not something beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import subprocess    
command = "mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql"
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.wait()
output = p.stdout.read()
p.stdout.close()
```

The var "output" will give you access to any error messages from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Popen opens a process, but it does not create a shell around it. Since I don't expect an intermediate shell, then I don't expect that the redirects there would be interpreted.
Popen does return file handles to the various streams in/out of the process - it would be stdout that you get without the redirects.

If you read and the store the content from those pipe handles, you can do the redirect inside the python code.

Perhaps you could consider the subprocess module - http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html - and you can specify what shell to use with it, which then can interpret the redirects.